# Importing data from excel and assigning a variable to each of its columns

Tags: import, data, excel, system-variables

How should I assign variables to the data imported from excel containing 3 columns which are time, mean and standard deviation. I want to perform operations on the three variables to get new variables.

The excel file can be found on the link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B26xdKbTd58_SVRlOEdNaVV4VGM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{time, mean, std} = 
  Transpose[Import["C:\\Users\\...\\Downloads\\MEANSDVALUES.xlsx"][[1]]] 
  (* use the appropriate directory for your file *)
```

Comment: Okay I tried this,thanks. Then I create an array say time_t of 130 elements in which i want to fill the elements of the above time matrix. How should i achieve this.?

Comment: @Pawan, not sure i understand; you mean something like `array=ConstantArray[0,3,130}];array[[All,;;109]]={time,mean,std}`?

Comment: I would like to add all the elements from a matrix into an array so that I can access each element as time_t[1,2]... and perform operations on them to get a new array.
For e.g.. For 2 matrices say time= {0,1,2...130} and mean={1.2,4.5,...}, whose elements need to be transferred into 2 arrays say time_t and mean_t
so that I can perform operations on the mean_t and time_t arrays to get new arrays(values) say time_t1 and mean_t1